# How to acces from live cd to windows 7 disks?

Tags: usb, windows-7, mount, live-usb, disk

I have live ubuntu 12.10 on usb (4GB verbatim). I prepared live usb by Lili USB creator (it just copy the iso of ubuntu to usb to be bootable). Then I booted successfully the live version of ubuntu from my usb. I wanted open windows 7 disk (NTFS) from devices but it gived me error (Škola is name of the disk): Unable to mount Škola, Adding read ACL for uid 999 to '/media/ubuntu' failed: operation not supported.
What should I do? I just need to access to windows disks cause windows crashed and I need backup some data before reinstall. 
Thx

Comment: Check if /media/ubuntu exist. If not, create it. then try and mount the drive. you will need to take ownership afterwards.

Comment: hey man thx, it helped just creating the directory /media/ubuntu :)

Comment: Great, Glad I can help. If it is answered please mark as so ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check if `/media/ubuntu` exist. If not, create it. then try and mount the drive.